# How should i track Objs in use, C#

Tags: c#

I have a manager that holds connections to the server. I keep the connection alive and i want my threads to request connections when it needs. My question is

How do i have track objects automatically? I would like it to work similar to scoped pointer. I request a connection, then when my obj goes out of scope it tells the manager it is not in use anymore. I wont be passing it around as a pointer. I'll be doing something like

```
{
Obj = Man.GetObj();
//some loop
    Obj.DoSomething()
} //auto tell man that obj is no longer in use
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create your own wrapper object and implements `IDisposable`. In the `Dispose()` method, signal the manager that you're no longer in use. You can then have your statement like...

```
using(Obj obj = Man.GetObj())
{
    Obj.DoSomething();
}
```

The `using` block automatically calls the `Dispose()` method at the close of the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the using statement.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Implement the IDisposable interface, and use the **using** keyword

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    void Dispose()
    {}
}

using(MyClass obj = Man.GetObj())
{
    obj.DoSomething();
}// obj.Dispose() will be called when the object goes out of scope.
```