# How do i add a IDisposable + delegate obj to an existing class

Tags: c#

I'm told what i want to do is impossible.
What i want to do is extend a class so it has an IDisposable obj which will call a delegate obj. The new class should work exactly like the base class (obj.BaseMethod() i dont want to do obj.theobj.BaseMethod()). Basically all i will be getting is the manager will know if an object that it has given a thread is out of scope or not in use anymore. How can i do this? (refer to this thread on what i am trying to do [How should i track Objs in use, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748591/how-should-i-track-objs-in-use-c))

Answer (score 1):

You could use AOP for this, such as Spring.NET, and just add the IDisposable interface and the necessary functions to your class.